# Proving that the midponts of an isosceles trapezoid are collinear

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I am trying to prove that the midpoints of the parallel sides of an isosceles trapezoid are perpendicular in order to prove that the lines have identical perpendicular bisectors, but I cannot find a way to prove such a thing.

Answer (score 2):

This question needs clarification and reformulation. For instance, what does it mean that "the midpoints of the parallel sides of an isosceles trapezoid are congruent" Two points are always congruent.

Comment: You are correct, that was a typo. i didn't mean that the two points were congruent, but rather that they are both perpendicular to each other. Like in [this diagram](http://i.imgur.com/qQPbNXq.png) i would be looking to see that HF is perpendicular to both CD and BA